# How do I get the text from a button in an Android application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a java application and I have run into a snag trying to get the text from a button. I have a layout created with a set number of buttons. Each button has a text value such as "1.0 Mev". I want to, when I click on this 1.0 MeV button, for the button text "1.0 MeV", to be deposited in a string variable. I have several buttons, so I want it to automatically pass the name of the button to the string variable of the button that I click but I seem to be failing at to grasp how to do this. Here is the relevant code I have towards performing these actions.

This is the xml code of the layout for the particular button.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/pointonemev_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:onClick="setEnergy"
android:text="@string/pointonemev_label"
android:textSize="12.5sp" />
```

So you can see that when the button is clicked it calls the method setEnergy

```
public void setEnergy(View view)
    {
        i = new Intent(this, chooseBodyRegion.class);
        Button energy = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
        energyChoice = (String) energy.getText();
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

The intent is declared as a global variable. Upon clicking the button and accessing this method, the startActivity will being it to the next class and the energyChoice variable should have something like "1.0 MeV" stored in it. But I have no idea how to use the getText() variable in the java application and I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you asking how you can send the `energyChoice` to the next `Activity`?

Comment: FYI - `chooseBodyRegion` is a class, and by convention should begin with a capital letter, `ChooseBodyRegion` or better yet `ChooseBodyRegionActivity`.

Comment: No, I know how to do that. I'm asking, how do I get the text, "1.0 MeV" which is what the name of the button is, inside the variable energyChoice. The intent is not the focus.

Comment: Oh... `energyChoice = energy.getText().toString()`

Comment: thats not working for me, for some reason. any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) method that `Button` inherits from `TextView`.  It returns a `CharSequence`, which you can just call `toString()` on.

```
energyChoice = energy.getText().toString();
```

Comment: It makes sense to me that this would work, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. What do you mean by the TextView? Isn't that a whole different thing in the layout by itself? I'm interested 0.1 MeV that appears on the button itself, though it doesn't seem like anything I'm doing is fixing the problem.

Comment: @user1985067 `TextView` is a class that `Button` extends, so your `Button` is a `TextView`.  Sorry I don't have my work machine set up for Android development, or I'd come up with a better (and tested) example.

Answer (score -1):

Use view.getText() to get the button's text.

Hope it helps.